# Java usage of HashMap or Map with multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap, sortedmap

I would like to use `HashMaps<String, V>` where the value type `V` should be a two dimensional `int` array (`int[][]`).

```
Map<String,int[][]> map = new HashMap<>();
int[][] a = new int[][]{ {1, 2} };
map.put("test", a);
System.out.println("Test:" + map.containsKey("test"));  // Test: true
System.out.println("key ==== " + map.get("test"));      // Key === [[I@19a8942
```

I am trying to have a key that access a unique value i.e. a 2-dimensional array, the size of the array is fixed `array[1][3]`, this is constant. Number of keys will grow with time but not the arrays. For example:

```
Key1 -> [no1, no2, no3]
key2 -> [no4, no5, no6]
```

1. I would like to access the array values, now I get an error.
2. Is there a better way of implementing this?. Ideally I would like it to be sorted by keys.

I am not an expert in Java but after some reading about maps I felt this works best for me.

Comment: What error do you get? You are dong it the right way.

Comment: If the key first dimension of the array wont change why don't you use something like this
HashMap<String,HashMap<String, Integer[]>> ?

Comment: @GonzaloNaveira. Why the HashMap for values?

Comment: Just because if he isn't using like a matrix I don't see the point of using two arrays!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to access the array values, now I get an error.

Not sure what you mean here, but you seem to be on the right track.

```
System.out.println(map.get("test")[0][1]);
```

```
2
```

---

> Ideally I would like it to be sorted by keys.

You can use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which is sorted on the natural ordering of its keys.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not produce any errors when I run it. However, you may be misinterpreting java's way of handling string representations of arrays as an error.

When you call `System.out.println("key ==== " + map.get("test"));` it does indeed correctly print the array. However, by default java expresses arrays oddly, especially arrays of arrays (or 2d arrays). You may want to change this to:

```
//at top of file
import java.util.Arrays;

//deepToString returns a string that expresses nested arrays in a user-friendly format
System.out.println("key ==== " + Arrays.deepToString(map.get("test")));
```

Which correctly prints

```
Test:true
key ==== [[1, 2]]
```

Comment: Thnx ValekHalfHeart, You are right it works, I am not an expert in java so I did not know this.

Comment: please dont mind, I accepted the other answer coz I wanted to access the elements. But your technique helped me for other cases.

Comment: @user2575429 I don't mind at all. It is your choice to accept whichever answer you feel solved your problem.